# Placing the comment form on a separate page

Tags: 7, comments

Is it possible to **place the comment form for a content type on a separate page?** I have some teasers on the home page and since I did them using Views, I need to find a way for people to add comments to it. If I can place a link which opens another page with *just* the comment form then that would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drupal has this built in, the link you are after is `comment/reply/[nid]`.

Comment: You can also configure per content type if the comment form should be on a separate page or not. If configured so, the default add comment link will point to that separate site.

Answer (score 9):

The page at admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type] contains the option "Show reply form on the same page as comments."

[image: screenshot]

When you deselect that option, the node pages appear as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Once you click on "Add new comment," you are redirected to comment/reply/[node-id]#comment-form, which shows the following form:

[image: screenshot]

When the option is selected, the node pages appear as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]