# Comment form on a separate page

Tags: comments

I want to have "Add new comment" link to open in a new page. I already read [Placing the comment form on a separate page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5332/placing-the-comment-form-on-a-separate-page), but this didn't solve my problem. When I go to /comment/reply/[nid] or /comment/reply/[nid]#comment-form, a page opens with "Add new comment" as the h1 page title. Then underneath the page title is my entire custom content type, followed by the comment form. I don't know why my content type is also displaying. In my content type, I've got "Show reply form on the same page as comments" unchecked. In the "Comment Fields" tab, I only have the fields I want on the comment form and no fields from my content type are listed. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem, what I had to do was:

```
function mymodule_page_alter(&$page) {  
    unset($page['content']['system_main']['comment_node']);
}
```

I'm not fond of having to do this, but I couldn't figure out why the content type was displaying.